# Package loading order questions need some work

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicates

Today, this question popped up:

- [Is there a hierarchy between packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155085/2693)

I was sure it was a duplicate, and found this question:

- [What's the right order when loading packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4515/2693) (First duplicate)

which then led me to this question:

- [Packages that need to be included in a specific order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3090/2693) (Second/main duplicate)

But this question simply points to an external link, something that at some point may go dead, and whose content we have no control over.  Surely we can do better than that? I'm always uncomfortable voting to close a question when the duplicates aren't really great answers.

A related question is much more helpful in this regard, but is focused on `hyperref` only:

- [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/2693)

I would suggest actually adding answers to the first duplicate question (which I think is a better question than the second duplicate (which is the current "main" duplicate)).

Comment: There are also a question of mine related (even if a little more specific with babel mention) : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150788/should-babel-package-call-be-placed-at-the-end-of-the-preamble There is definitively the need for organization here.